# What is the proper name for small uninsulated ground posts

Tags: connector, identification, grounding

I am looking for some of the small uninsulated posts used for grounding on bench test equipment such as oscilloscopes. They are usually used for establishing a common ground when measuring small signals.  They usually have a knurled nut, and are cross drilled, so suitable for rings, forks, and bare wire.  A bit like a 5-way binding post but much smaller and not insulated from the panel they are mounted in.  Here are a couple of examples (click for larger):

[image]
[image]

But when I search the usual distributors for "binding post" "ground post" "ground terminal" etc, I'm not finding these.  Nor am I finding the parts direct from manufacturers on google. Presumably I am using the wrong search term. What would you call these?

Comment: I found an "Uninsulated Earthing Terminal Safety Bonding Ground Grounding Post" on UK ebay: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Uninsulated-Earthing-Terminal-Safety-Bonding-Ground-Grounding-Post-/121719116981 if that gives you somewhere to start from (that one isn't cross-drilled). I searched Google for "earthing post".

Comment: Also available as a "turntable earth terminal".

Comment: It might be that those instruments use custom-made parts. If you want hundreds or more of them in the quality-cost balance you want, a local machine shop will be able to make them.

Comment: Ive had a look with those search terms (thanks for the suggestion!) but I'm still not having much luck.  We do have some friendly machine shops, but I don't fancy complicating my supply chain for this product over it. It occurs to me that I usually see these on older kit (or kit which has been in production for a long time) so I guess they may have fallen out of fashion.

Comment: Maybe you could use threadlocker on a brass or nickel-plated M3/M4 bolt to secure it in the chassis and add a generic knurled thumb nut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there isn't a particular name for these.  An example part I have now found is Cinch/Johnson/Belfuse [111-2223-001](https://www.belfuse.com/product/part-details?partn=111-2223-001), and the datasheet calls it a "*Binding Post - Uninsulated With Knurled Thumb - Nut-Grounded Type*".

[image]